# RectTransform узнать ширину и высоту между якорями

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как узнать высоту между якорями, если они сделаны во весь блок, с авто-подстройкой, при смене разрешения.

Так-как `RectTransform.sizeDelta` возвращает `{0,0}` когда якоря на весь блок, то при расчетах ниже, точки появляются в центре, за место того, чтобы появиться там, где указан `TargetPosition`.

Чем можно заменить такой код:

```
Vector3 CorrectPosition = TargetPosition + OffSet;
Vector2 vp2 = MapCamera.WorldToViewportPoint(CorrectPosition);
Vector2 position = new Vector2(
   (vp2.x * Rect.sizeDelta.x) - (Rect.sizeDelta.x * 0.5f), 
   (vp2.y * Rect.sizeDelta.y) - (Rect.sizeDelta.y * 0.5f)
);

if (OffScreen) {
    position.x = Mathf.Clamp(position.x, -((Rect.sizeDelta.x * 0.5f) - BorderOffScreen), ((Rect.sizeDelta.x * 0.5f) - BorderOffScreen));
    position.y = Mathf.Clamp(position.y, -((RectRoot.sizeDelta.y * 0.5f) - BorderOffScreen), ((Rect.sizeDelta.y * 0.5f) - BorderOffScreen));
}
float size = Size;
if (position.x == (Rect.sizeDelta.x * 0.5f) - BorderOffScreen || position.y == (Rect.sizeDelta.y * 0.5f) - BorderOffScreen ||
    position.x == -(Rect.sizeDelta.x * 0.5f) - BorderOffScreen || -position.y == (Rect.sizeDelta.y * 0.5f) - BorderOffScreen) {
    size = OffScreenSize;
} else {
    size = Size;
}
```

Чтобы правильно считались позиции?
Никак не могу найти решение, это было последнее, что я написал и пытался исправить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен через добавление спрайта и слоя к элементу, а после чего, просто скрываем слой на основной камере и показываем на второй камере.

Answer (score 0):

ну попробуй так

```
RectTransform rt = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
RectTransform parent = (RectTransform)rt.parent;
Vector2 parentSize = parent.rect.size;

Vector2 d = rt.anchorMax - rt.anchorMin;
float width = d.x * parentSize.x;
float heigh = d.y * parentSize.y;

Debug.Log("width: " + width.ToString());
Debug.Log("height: " + heigh.ToString());
```

использовал размеры родителя,   потому что якорьки напрямую зависят от него

Comment: 0 Выводит. Мне нужно добиться результата, чтобы на RectTransform был расчет позиции объекта который стоит на террейне,и мне нужно вывести иконку на картинку в той же позиции, как это сделать, не пойму никак.

Comment: @Vendor аа ты типо хош сделать как делают например полоски здоровья у персонажей в играх ?? ну типо чтоб полоска над бошкой у персонажа была , но повёрнута всегда в сторону экрана, а когда персонаж не попадает в камеру , то полоска с его здоровьем остается в пределах экрана. Чтото типо этого ??

Comment: нее я делаю миникарту и мне нужно иконки вывести в той - же позиции, что и объект, а не получается, выводятся в других позициях, понять не могу, почему так происходит.

Comment: Нужно, чтобы работало как `sizeDelta`, есть мысли? То есть фактически `sizeDelta` смотрит расстояние между якорями, если якоря фиксированных размеров, а когда используешь растяжку (stretch) то тогда возвращает `{0,0}`, как сделать аналог `sizeDelta`, чтобы работало точно также но при растяжке, авто-подстройки элемента под экран?

Comment: @Vendor тю так sizeDelta возвращает не рассояние между якорьками, а размер самого элемента, если anchorMin = anchorMax, если же у тебя ты говоришь подстраивается под экран, то размер элемента ты можешь узнать так: rectTransform.rect.size, свойство rect.size хранит размер элемента независимо от якорьков. Попробуй